# Passing all the parameters in a Bash script

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

In my script, I use `awk`, the options are hardcoded but the file name is not, so I have `awk options $1` If I wanted a 2 files version I would do `awk options $1 $2`.

How to do it for arbitrary number of files? (`$1` up to `"$last"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redesign your script to use `"$@"`; or you can check `$#` and run your commands accordingly.

[Bash Reference Manual](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Special-Parameters) states:

> `$@` Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word. That is, `"$@"` is equivalent to `"$1" "$2" …`. […] When there are no positional parameters, `"$@"` and `$@` expand to nothing (i.e., they are removed).

```
awk options "$@"
```

If you need to use few command line parameters that are not filenames, take a look at `shift` builtin.

> `$#` Expands to the number of positional parameters in decimal.

Use it with some conditionals if you need to invoke different commands, depending on this number.